# Adding a label to the bottom right corner of a cell

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

I am adding a label dynamically and want to place that label on the bottom right corner of the cell.

The code i use is :

```
 Panel pnlAddBundle = new Panel();
 pnlAddBundle.Controls.Add(new Label("<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;">" + ("Build " + gate.a) + "</div>"));
tc.Controls.Add(pnlAddBundle );
```

Can anyone help me with this ? I get error and in the bottom it does not gets added
What changes I should make ?

I do not want to make a css for this. as it gets override with other css.

Answer (score 1):

Labels cannot be used for positioning. To accomplish what you're looking for, you will need to put that label inside of a div and apply absolute positioning to it. Here is an example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/k521h7r4/

If you need to do it dynamically in code, you can make one of the outer divs a Panel and add your Label controls to that.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.outer-div {
        position:relative;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        margin:5px;   
    }

    div.inner-div {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
</style>
<div class="outer-div">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="inner-div">
        <!-- render labels inside of here -->
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

And in code-behind:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Hello World!";
Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

**EDIT**

Another option you could consider is using a literal control instead of a label if you want to render the HTML dynamically. It's an ugly approach, but looks like it would work based on your example above.

Comment: Panel pnlAddBundle = new Panel();
                    pnlAddBundle.Controls.Add(new Label("<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;">" + ("Build " + gate.BundleMaxValue) + "</div>"));

I tried this :

Comment: I am trying to add the panel and label dynamicaaly. Moreover, I do not wish to provide a css as it gets override with my other code.

Comment: Labels render as a span in the browser, which is an inline element. The code in the comment above would render a div inside of a span, which would not work and is semantically incorrect.

Comment: You would be adding CSS to the parent Panel control, which would take care of positioning any child controls rendered within. There is no way to get around using CSS for this.